# Get the result of aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/mykey/ in python3

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

How can I retrieve the same result of that bash command in python?
I've tried using list_objects_v2 from boto3 but I dont want all objects, just the next file names.

Comment: What do you mean? How did you exactly used `list_objects_v2`?

Comment: With Bucket, Prefix and StartAfter parameters, it returns the key of all objects in that path, I mean, if prefix and startafter are 'a/b/', I don' want all a/b/c/whatever.csv, I just want a list of those different 'c'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to exclude the prefix path from the list of objects.

The name (Key) of objects in Amazon S3 include their full path. Therefore, you can simply remove the prefix from the key:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

PREFIX = 'mykey/'

for object in s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket').objects.filter(Prefix=PREFIX):
    print(object.key[len(PREFIX):]) # This skips-over the prefix
```

Here is the equivalent using `boto3.client`:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

PREFIX = 'mykey/'

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket', Prefix=PREFIX)

for object in response['Contents']:
    print(object['Key'][len(PREFIX):]) # This skips-over the prefix
```